# Icon in my taskbar becomes corrupt on execution

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, icons

I have a program that seems to have a valid icon in my task bar, but when I go to execute the program a bad/missing/corrupt (place holder) icon is displayed. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the program. I even tried to delete the local icon cache. Additionally, I tried to change the bit depth to 16 bits and then deleted my local icon cache and reverting back to 32-bit color depth, but still nothing. I am at a loss and I hope you all have some insight that I do not. The only thing I have not tried yet is to delete the local user profile. This is for an enterprise environment.

Comment: Go to `%appdata%/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Quick Launch/User Pinned/Taskbar`, right click on the application, properties, Change Icon. Try reselecting the icon

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Sorry but this site is not for "*issues specific to corporate IT support and networks*" per the **[help]**. Considering you have stated this is an enterprise environment, it makes it off topic.

Comment: @CharlieRB I disagree, unless you have an alternative location for this question. The way I see it you do not want to assist because I mentioned it being on an enterprise network. Since this is only affecting one of many computers I do not believe group policy or the fact that its on a domain is relevant to this issue, so please do not brush off my need for help.

Comment: I don't make the rules for this site. It is in the Super User guidelines referenced in my previous comment. You are correct that I do not want to assist. That is because I do not want to be responsible for any company policies you may be violating. I am not brushing off your need for help. It is your IT department's responsibility to resolve issues with their assets. Contact your IT department.

Comment: @CharlieRB Look I head IT at my company and I make the policies, so when I run into something that I cannot fix which is extremely seldom. I seek help from online communities. Anyway. I was able to solve my problem. It was a corrupt user profile. I just wish that I didn't have to completely delete the profile to fix the issue. I appreciate your attempt at assisting me none-the-less.

Answer (score 0):

**The Issue:**
Desktop Icon is not correct when application opens, it appears as a place holder.

**Recommended Solution:**
If deleting the local icon cache does not solve your issue and neither does switching to a different bit depth, then you must delete the local user profile.

**How To:**

***NOTE:** Before you start be sure to make a copy of your local profile directory in C:\Users\ so that you may extract any files that are important to keep.

1) Open start menu

2) Windows + R

3) Type: sysdm.cpl to open ​System Properties

​4) Open the Advanced tab

5) Select the Settings... ​option under User Profile

6) Select the offending ​profile and click delete and ​OK.

When you log back into the computer a new user profile will be populated, and it will be default. The only caveat is that you will not be able to keep any personalized settings, or local files.